# Expected unqualified-id for @class AVPlayerLayer

Tags: c++, objective-c, qt, avfoundation, objective-c++

Inside my qt application I have declared a `@class AVPlayerLayer` inside my header file (`frame.h`) which in the source file (`frame.mm`) includes `<AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>`.

When I try to compile it with qt creator I get the following error:

```
Expected unqualified-id for @class AVPlayerLayer
unknown type name 'AVPlayerLayer'
```

I'm trying to forward the class declaration as I want my header file to know to expect `AVPlayerLayer` which is included inside my `.mm` file with `AVFoundation`, the reason I'm doing this is because header files can not contain `Objective-C` code.

frame.h:

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QQuickItem>

typedef struct __CVBuffer *CVBufferRef;
typedef CVBufferRef CVImageBufferRef;
typedef CVImageBufferRef CVOpenGLESTextureRef;
typedef CVOpenGLESTextureRef CVOGLTextureRef;

@class AVPlayerLayer;
//-----------------

class FrameRenderer : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    CVOGLTextureRef renderLayerToTexture(AVPlayerLayer *layer);

public:
    FrameRenderer(QAbstractVideoSurface *surface, QObject *parent = 0);
};
```

frame.mm

```
#include "frame.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

FrameRenderer::FrameRenderer(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
{
}

CVOGLTextureRef FrameRenderer::renderLayerToTexture(AVPlayerLayer *layer)
{
    size_t dummyWidth = 0, dummyHeight = 0;
    return createCacheTextureFromLayer(layer, dummyWidth, dummyHeight);
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], we can't correct code we can't see

Comment: Sorry, I added sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://philjordan.eu/article/mixing-objective-c-c++-and-objective-c++

You can forward declare your objective c class with:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
@class AVPlayerLayer;
#else
typedef struct objc_object AVPlayerLayer;
#endif
```

Comment: Thank you, this fixed my problem.